# Unhandled rejection Error in plugin "webpack-stream"

Tags: webpack, gulp, babeljs, babel-loader

In going through and updating all the npm packages in a React application, I've encountered an error when performing a `gulp build` command from the terminal.

`Unhandled rejection Error in plugin "webpack-stream"
Message: Module build failed
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.`

The files where it seems to be encountering the problem are in the third-party npm_modules babel-loader and babel-preset-react. I've verified that all these "dependencies" are upgraded to the most current general release, and even tried the @latest version, but with no change in behavior - I'm still unable to produce a successful gulp build of my project.

package.json file:

    `{
      "name": "",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "apps/poc/index.html",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "array.prototype.find": "^2.0.3",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "base64-js": "^1.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "chance": "^1.0.16",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "history": "^4.6.3",
        "immutability-helper": "^2.7.1",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "moment-range": "^4.0.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
        "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
        "object-entries": "^1.0.0",
        "object-keys": "^1.0.12",
        "object.entries": "^1.0.4",
        "object.values": "^1.0.4",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
        "query-string": "^6.1.0",
        "react": "^16.5.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
        "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^5.1.0",
        "react-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
        "react-datetime": "^2.15.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
        "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.6",
        "react-portal": "^4.1.5",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-redux-toastr": "^7.4.0",
        "react-router": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
        "react-timeago": "^4.1.9",
        "react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
        "react-transition-group": "^2.4.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.0",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
        "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
        "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.2.0",
        "redux-idle-monitor": "^0.10.2",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "reselect": "^3.0.1",
        "should": "^13.2.3",
        "signature_pad": "^2.3.2",
        "simple-react-bootstrap-button-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
        "string.prototype.startswith": "^0.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.1.5",
        "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^6.13.0",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.13.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "chokidar": "^2.0.4",
        "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
        "del": "^3.0.0",
        "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
        "eslint": "^5.5.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
        "express": "^4.14.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "faker": "^4.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "glob": "^7.1.3",
        "graceful-fs": "^4.1.11",
        "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
        "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-changed": "^3.2.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
        "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
        "gulp-less": "^4.0.1",
        "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
        "gulp-mocha": "^6.0.0",
        "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-print": "^5.0.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
        "gulp-task-listing": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
        "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
        "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1",
        "gulp-wrapper": "^1.0.0",
        "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
        "json-schema-faker": "^0.4.0",
        "livereload": "^0.7.0",
        "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
        "node-notifier": "^5.0.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
        "postcss": "^7.0.2",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "source-map": "^0.7.3",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
        "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
        "webpack": "^4.18.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4",
        "webpack-stream": "^5.1.1",
        "yargs": "^12.0.2"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp build",
        "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp watch",
        "run-dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d --progress --colors --display-error-details",
        "run-prod": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p --progress --colors --display-error-details",
        "profile-dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --profile -d --progress --colors --display-error-details --json > stats.json",
        "profile-prod": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --profile -p --progress --colors --display-error-details --json > stats.json",
        "serve-cold": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --inline",
        "serve-hot": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --inline --hot",
        "serve-api": "node server.express.js",
        "watch-dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch -d --progress --colors --display-error-details",
        "watch-prod": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch -p --progress --colors --display-error-details",
        "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp postinstall"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": ""
    }`

gulpfile.babel.js
`

```
'use strict';
/// <binding BeforeBuild='build:jsx' AfterBuild='build' ProjectOpened='watch, build' />
/* This file in the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins. Click here to learn more. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007 */

// TODO: 
// *- handle dev vs. production
// *- webpackStream modes

const gulp = require('gulp');
const $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true });
//const fs = require('fs');
//const path = require('path');
//const glob = require('glob');
const args = require('yargs').argv;
const config = require('./gulp.config')();
const del = require('del');
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
const merge = require('merge-stream');
const autoprefixer = new require('autoprefixer')({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] });
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
const consoleStats = {
  colors: true,
  exclude: ["node_modules"],
  chunks: false,
  assets: false,
  timings: true,
  modules: false,
  hash: false,
  version: false
};

config.verbose = args.verbose || config.verbose;
config.isProduction = args.isProduction || config.isProduction;

if (config.isProduction) {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
  log('***** PRODUCTION BUILD *****');
} else {
  log('***** DEBUG BUILD *****');
}

//*********************
// Dev Tasks
//*********************

gulp.task('clean', cleanSourceFolders);
gulp.task('build:jsx', buildJSX);
gulp.task('build:scss', buildCSS);
gulp.task('copy:static-content', copyStaticContent);
gulp.task('copy:bootstrap-sass', buildBootstrapPostInstall);
gulp.task('notify:build', displayBuildStart);
gulp.task('notify:build:end', displayBuildEnd);
gulp.task('watch:jsx', watchJSX);
gulp.task('watch:scss', watchSCSS);
gulp.task('watch:static-content', watchStaticContent);
gulp.task('postinstall', gulp.series('copy:bootstrap-sass'));

gulp.task(
  'build',
  gulp.series(
    //displayBuildStart,
    "clean",
    gulp.parallel(
      'build:jsx',
      'build:scss'
    ),
    // DLW: 'postinstall',
    'copy:static-content'
    //displayBuildEnd
));

gulp.task('watch',
  function () {
    gulp.watch('watch:scss', watchSCSS());
    gulp.watch('watch:jsx', watchJSX());
});

function log(msg) {
  "use strict";

  if (typeof msg === 'object') {
    for (let item in msg) {
      if (msg.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg[item]));
      }
    }
  } else {
    $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg));
  }
}

function displayNotification(msg) {
  return notifier.notify({
    title: 'Gulp -- Building',
    message: msg,
    icon: __dirname + '/node_modules/gulp-notify/assets/gulp.png'
  });
}

function cleanSourceFolders(cb) {
  let destinationPaths = [
    config.paths.webCss,
    config.paths.webFonts,
    config.paths.webImages,
    config.paths.webJs //,
    // DLW config.paths.webRoot
  ];

  destinationPaths.map(path => {
    console.log("Cleaning path :" + path);
    del(path + '*').then(paths => {
      if (config.verbose) {
        paths.forEach(function (path) {
          log($.util.colors.magenta(path));
        });
      }
    })
  });

  cb();
}

function displayBuildStart(cb) {
  displayNotification('Building...');
  cb();
}

function displayBuildEnd(cb) {
  displayNotification('Build complete.');
  cb();
}

function buildJSX() {
  let webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

  // output.path conflicts with gulp.dest below, so we remove it
  delete webpackConfig.output.path;

  return gulp.src(config.paths.sourceRoot)
    .pipe($.changed(config.paths.webJs))
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig, webpack))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.webJs));
}

// Compile SASS/SCSS to CSS
function buildCSS() {
  "use strict";

  log('Compiling SCSS --> CSS');

  return gulp
    .src(config.paths.scssSource)
    .pipe($.changed(config.paths.webCss))
    .pipe($.plumber({
      errorHandler: $.notify.onError({
        title: 'Gulp -- Build',
        message: "Error: <%= error.message %>"
      })
    }))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    // perform scss compilation w/auto-prefixing
    .pipe($.sass().on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.postcss([autoprefixer]))
    .pipe($.wrapper({ header: config.header }))
    // write non-minified version
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.webCss))
    //.pipe($.cssmin())
    .pipe($.rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe($.wrapper({ header: config.header }))
    // write minified/source-mapped version
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.webCss));
}

// NOTE: The following task is referenced by package.json (post-install task)
function buildBootstrapPostInstall() {
  // Copies the installed version of bootstrap-sass to the scss source folder
  return gulp.src(config.paths.nodeModules + 'bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/**/*.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.sourceRoot + 'scss/bootstrap'));
}

function copyStaticContent() {
  let contentFiles = gulp.src([
    config.paths.imageSource,
    config.paths.htmlSource
  ],
  {
    base: config.paths.sourceRoot
  })
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.webRoot));

  // Fonts and static css files need to be handled separately because
  // some source locations are in the node_modules folder (which
  // does not share a common sourceRoot/base folder)
  let cssFiles = gulp.src(config.paths.cssSource)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.webCss));

  let fontFiles = gulp.src(config.paths.fontSource)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.webFonts));

  // let boostrapTheme = gulp.src(config.paths.fontSource)
  //    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.webFonts));

  return merge(contentFiles, fontFiles, cssFiles);
}

function watchJSX() {
  const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
  const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
  const server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler,
    {
      publicPath: config.paths.webRoot,
      hot: true,
      stats: consoleStats
    });

  server.listen(8080,
    () => {});
}

function watchSCSS() {
  console.log('Watching SCSS...');
  return gulp.watch(config.paths.scssSource, buildCSS);
}

function watchStaticContent() {
  let base = config.paths.sourceRoot,
    source = [
      config.paths.htmlSource,
      config.paths.imageSource
    ],
    dest = config.paths.webRoot;

  return gulp.src(source, { base: base })
    .pipe($.if(config.verbose, $.print()))
    .pipe($.watch(source, { base: base }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}
```

`

Comment: Please share your `gulpfile.js` and `package.json`.

Comment: @sdgluck I've added the package.json and gulpfile.babel.js in hopes that will help reveal something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you have a mismatch between the version of Babel core and the Babel plugins/presets that you are using. You have `@babel/core` at major version 7 but all your plugins and presets at major version 6.

Update all your plugins and presets to major version 7. You can use [`babel-upgrade`](https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade) to help you.

Comment: That got me one step closer, anyway...and, wow...it added a ton of dependencies that I didn't have previously in the package.json file. I'm still seeing the Unhandled rejection Error in plugin "webpack-stream" but now it's barking on loading a JSON file, which, I think, webpack 4 is supposed to do as base functionality. I even added json-loader and that didn't resolve the problem, either.

Comment: @rcastagna You can open a new question for that, if it's still a problem for you.